# Update a Relationship Model with one Line - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have a massive edit page and the values are taken from 4 tables. I have them all in a object and sorted which ones go where. Although when I call my main model, can I update its relationship by passing in the object or array?

Main Model

```
$officiant = Officiant::find($id);
```

Its relationship is the "detail" and "profile"

Example:

```
    $officiant->fname = $request->fname;
    $officiant->lname = $request->lname;
    $officiant->phone = $request->phone;


    $profile = new \StdClass();
    $profile->gender = $request->gender;
    $profile->profile = $request->profile;



    $detail = new \StdClass();
    $detail->street = $request->street;
    $detail->city = $request->city;
```

I can update officiant by passing it like this

```
$officiant->update(array ($officiant));
```

Although, can I update the detail one by doing something similar, as in

```
$officiant->detail->update(array ($detail));
$officiant->profileupdate(array ($profile));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are updating via a relation ship it should be

```
$officiant->detail()->update(array ($detail));
```

Using ->detail() instead of ->detail sends a query builder instance that can be chained with update().